# .NET Core - Using multiple authentication schemes with a dedicated Authentication API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to create a dedicated authentication API to which my other APIs will refer to when authenticating credentials. According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-multiple-authentication-schemes), I could do that using multiple authentication schemes, by using a similar piece of code below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Code omitted for brevity

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000/identity/";
        })
        .AddJwtBearer("AzureAD", options =>
        {
            ...
        });
}
```

Some questions I have about this:

1. I'm guessing this code will go to my other APIs, and the `options.Authority` will have to change to the URL pointing towards my authentication API endpoint, right?
2. If #1 is right, how should the `identity` endpoint of the authentication API look like, exactly?
3. This is not in the code above, but what is the difference between `options.Authority` and the `ValidIssuer` of `options.TokenValidationParameters`? They kinda seem similar to me; don't they both point to the issuer of the JWT token for authorization? Should I use one over the other on my other APIs, as opposed to my authentication API?

Thank you for any help you can provide me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes this is the code of the configuration of the authentication on your e.g. APIs
2. most likely it is an [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) / [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) endpoint implemented for example with an [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver.io) (though there are others).
3. Yes, they are the same in most cases. And there is also the option of `ValidIssuers` (multiple). The libraries take the `Authority` property for connecting to the auth server and discovering the `/.well-known/openid-configuration`. In some special cases of network setups you may do not want to use the public domain but an internal domain or IP as authority. In that case (if not configured otherwise) the auth server would still return the configured/public domain as issuer. Then `Authority` and `ValidIssuer` would be different. As long you do not have the need/requirement to explicitly change/tinker those values they are the same in most cases.